# Spring MVC Form Submit - Dynamically change the form catching Object

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My Spring framework version 3.1.4

**Question ???** Is there is any way to dynamically change the form catching Object depending on the some criteria.

Its really tough to explain, I will do my best here

### JAVA OBJECTS

I have a Java Object `PatientDocument.java`

```
public class PatientDocument{

    @Id
    protected String documentId;

    @Indexed
    protected String patientId;

    @Indexed
    protected Integer documentType;

    protected Object document;

}
```

The field `document` in above class can have any datatype objects depending upon the value in field `documentType` Eg : If documentType is 1, the Object representing the field 'document' will be `MedicalCertificate.Java` and I'm storing the PatientDocument into MongoDB collection.

`MedicalCertificate.java` looks like

```
public class MedicalCertificate {

    protected String complaint;
    protected String suggestedRestingDays;
    protected Integer treatingDoctor;
    protected Integer medicalDirector;

}
```

### CLIENT SIDE

I'm using Thymeleaf for my client side rendering

My patientDocument.html looks like

```
<form action="#" id="patientDocument" th:action="@{/emr/patient/document/save}" th:object="${patientDocument}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- #### HIDDEN FIELDS #### -->
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{documentId}" class="col-xs-12" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{documentType}" class="col-xs-12" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{patientId}" class="col-xs-12" readonly="readonly"/>

    <!-- Medical Certificate -->
    <section th:if="${patientDocument.documentType == 1}" layout:include="@{emr/patient/medicalCertificate} :: main"></section>

    <!-- Referal Letter -->
    <section th:if="${patientDocument.documentType == 2}" layout:include="@{emr/patient/referalLetter} :: main"></section>

    <!-- Acknowledgment Form -->
    <section th:if="${patientDocument.documentType == 3}" layout:include="@{emr/patient/acknowledgeForm} :: main"></section>

<form>
```

medicalCertificate.html looks like

```
<section layout:fragment="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Complaint</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <textarea rows="5" th:field="*{document.complaint}" class="col-xs-12"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Rest For</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{document.suggestedRestingDays}" class="col-xs-12"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Treated By</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{document.treatingDoctor}" readonly="readonly"/>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{document.treatingDoctorName}" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Medical Director</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{document.medicalDirector}" readonly="readonly"/>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{document.medicalDirectorName}" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>
```

### View Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/document/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePatientDocument(@ModelAttribute PatientDocument patientDocument, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

        logger.debug("Executing save for Patient Document : {}", patientDocument.toString());
        ////Logic to the Service Layer                   

}
```

**Explanation of the Questions** :  As you can see the `patientDocument.html` the Client side form content corresponding to field 'document' will be replaced by Thymeleaf Fragments depending on documentType field. So when i submit the form into view controller the Object patientDocument contains the MedicalCertificate fields in place of field 'document'. Thats alright !!!

Now in View Controller, i need to say to the submit handler that "Hey, a `PatientDocument.java` object is coming as form submit. But the object inside the field 'document' will be 'MedicalCertificate.java'"

Where can i specify that?? Is there is any way to do it in SPRING MVC??

I need to alter the `patientDocument.java` Object as below before the Catching the client side form submit. But how?

```
PatientDocument patientDocument = new PatientDocument();
patientDocument.setDocument(new MedicalCertificate());
```

Thanks in advance

Good Day

Comment: I tried a lot to understand your problem, but its like hitting my head on hard rock. Could be you more specific to your problem?

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena Thanks for your time, As i mentioned, it was a bit tough to explain for me, sorry for the inconvenience. cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Change your container class to:

```
public class PatientDocument{
  @Id
  protected String documentId;

  @Indexed
  protected String patientId;

  @Indexed
  protected Integer documentType;

  protected AcknowledgeForm acknowledgeForm;

  protected MedicalCertificate medicalCertificate;

  protected ReferalLetter referalLetter;
}
```

Then, form fields in `medicalCertificate.html` would look like:

```
<textarea rows="5" th:field="*{medicalCertificate.complaint}" class="col-xs-12"></textarea>
<input type="text" th:field="*{medicalCertificate.suggestedRestingDays}" class="col-xs-12"/>
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{medicalCertificate.treatingDoctor}" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type="text" th:field="*{medicalCertificate.treatingDoctorName}" class="form-control"/>
```

You will have to make similar changes to the other forms.  Then, you can read the required property of `PatientDocument` based on its `documentType`.

---

**Option 2**: Write a `PropertyEditor` for `PatientDocument` to parse the request and set the document based on the request parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will leave option 1, since the document type will grow largly in future. option 2 sounds good. can you help me a bit more to write `propertyEeditor` in this case. Sorry for the Late response.

Comment: By ruling out option 1 you are looking for a `PropertyEditor` that gets an entire `HttpServletRequest` so that it can examine each and every form field. The `PropertyEditor` will then construct an object based on the information it finds in the submitted form. The trouble is that the `PropertyEditor` implementation you will provide will be a sub-class of `java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport`, which has no dependency on `HttpServletRequest`. So, there isn't an easy example of implementing option 2. You will have to go through the Spring MVC documentation to develop your own solution.

Comment: Well, That's make sense to me. Thanks once again